# Run python script in remote machine without using SCP

Tags: python, ssh, scp, remote-server

There is any possibility to run the python script in remote machine with out transfer files using SCP or better method? I have search a lot of libraries for solve this issue. But did not find the best solution for it.

I have found some libraries which perform SSH and SCP to remote machine using python script. In their approach first copy files to remote system using SCP and execute command over SSH.

Thanking you

Answer (score 1):

You could use [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).

Obviously it does depend on what exactly you want your remote python script to do, but it has a lot of helper functions for interacting with the OS including file upload & download but it's written all in Python.

Comment: Hi @justcompile It is also similar to Paramiko library. So we need to upload our file to remote system so there is any better idea with out download and upload files?

Comment: I believe it sits on top of Paramiko. As I say you can upload via fabric, but the other alternative would be to install your script via pip from a repository which would include your dependencies (which you could do via fabric) and then invoke it using fabric or via the command flag as suggested by @alfie

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `python` with a flag to read the script from its standard input, and then feed the script to the python instance through the ssh connection, for example:

```
cat /some/script.py | ssh user@host 'python -'
```

Running `python -` will cause the python interpreter to read the script from the process's standard input. In this case, the standard input of the `ssh` process is passed to the remote system as the standard input of the python instance.

You can supply additional command-line arguments to the python script, if desired:

```
cat /some/script.py | ssh user@host 'python - arg1 arg2...'
```

Note that any `import` statements in the python script will be resolved on the remote system, so  the script has to limit itself to modules which are available to the remote python interpreter.

Comment: That method using `python -` covers the stdin, so if the Python script wants to read from stdin, that isn't possible anymore.  But in many cases this should be no problem.  If it is, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
ssh remotehost python -c "'print(5)'"
```

A script needs not to be copied to execute it.  The Python interpreter can run a script which is given as argument.

Double quoting is necessary (and will quickly become a hassle) because one level of quoting is removed by the `ssh` call and another is still necessary to group the script into one argument for the `python` call.

Multiline is also no problem:

```
ssh remotehost python -c "'             
import random
print(random.random())'"
```

will print something like

```
0.998373816572
```

Just be aware of the quoting stuff when you use `'` or `"` in your Python script as well.

Another option is to have the script in a variable and then use `printf` to quote the contents properly:

```
a='             
import random
print(random.random())'
# or use something like a=$(cat myscript.py)

ssh ttiqadm@ttiq-hv02 python -c "$(printf "%q" "$a")"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @Alfe But I want to implement this in python script not using shell commands. I want execute some functions or classes in same python script not a whole script. Because lot of dependencies are may not be available in remote system(packages).

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question.  Then I suggest to go with @justcompile's answer and use fabric.  It's a widely known and used library for exactly this purpose.